# Deserialise JSON object to string or concrete type based on status code returned

Tags: c#, json, serialization

This is my `Rootobject` class, generated from 'Paste special' in VS.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string formatVersion { get; set; }
    public Matrix[][] matrix { get; set; }
    public Summary summary { get; set; }
}

public class Summary
{
    public int successfulRoutes { get; set; }
    public int totalRoutes { get; set; }
}

public class Matrix
{
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public object response { get; set; }
    public Detailederror detailedError { get; set; }
}

public class Detailederror
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

This is modelled from:

```
{
    "formatVersion": "0.0.1",
    "matrix": [
        [
            {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "response": {
                    "routeSummary": {
                        "lengthInMeters": 95028,
                        "travelTimeInSeconds": 4581,
                        "trafficDelayInSeconds": 0,
                        "trafficLengthInMeters": 0,
                        "departureTime": "2021-10-03T09:48:17+01:00",
                        "arrivalTime": "2021-10-03T11:04:38+01:00"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "response": {
                    "routeSummary": {
                        "lengthInMeters": 97955,
                        "travelTimeInSeconds": 4928,
                        "trafficDelayInSeconds": 0,
                        "trafficLengthInMeters": 0,
                        "departureTime": "2021-10-03T09:48:17+01:00",
                        "arrivalTime": "2021-10-03T11:10:25+01:00"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "response": {
                    "routeSummary": {
                        "lengthInMeters": 105077,
                        "travelTimeInSeconds": 4725,
                        "trafficDelayInSeconds": 0,
                        "trafficLengthInMeters": 0,
                        "departureTime": "2021-10-03T09:48:17+01:00",
                        "arrivalTime": "2021-10-03T11:07:01+01:00"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "response": {
                    "routeSummary": {
                        "lengthInMeters": 108004,
                        "travelTimeInSeconds": 5072,
                        "trafficDelayInSeconds": 0,
                        "trafficLengthInMeters": 0,
                        "departureTime": "2021-10-03T09:48:17+01:00",
                        "arrivalTime": "2021-10-03T11:12:48+01:00"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "response": {
                    "routeSummary": {
                        "lengthInMeters": 103661,
                        "travelTimeInSeconds": 4624,
                        "trafficDelayInSeconds": 0,
                        "trafficLengthInMeters": 0,
                        "departureTime": "2021-10-03T09:48:17+01:00",
                        "arrivalTime": "2021-10-03T11:05:21+01:00"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "response": {
                    "routeSummary": {
                        "lengthInMeters": 106588,
                        "travelTimeInSeconds": 4971,
                        "trafficDelayInSeconds": 0,
                        "trafficLengthInMeters": 0,
                        "departureTime": "2021-10-03T09:48:17+01:00",
                        "arrivalTime": "2021-10-03T11:11:08+01:00"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "statusCode": 400,
                "response": "Engine error while executing route request: MAP_MATCHING_FAILURE: Origin (0, 0)",
                "detailedError": {
                    "message": "Engine error while executing route request: MAP_MATCHING_FAILURE: Origin (0, 0)",
                    "code": "MAP_MATCHING_FAILURE"
                }
            },
            {
                "statusCode": 400,
                "response": "Engine error while executing route request: MAP_MATCHING_FAILURE: Origin (0, 0)",
                "detailedError": {
                    "message": "Engine error while executing route request: MAP_MATCHING_FAILURE: Origin (0, 0)",
                    "code": "MAP_MATCHING_FAILURE"
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "summary": {
        "successfulRoutes": 6,
        "totalRoutes": 8
    }
}
```

However, the status code for a `Matrix` object can be either 200 OK or 400 for each item in the list.

```
public class Matrix
{
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public object response { get; set; }
    public Detailederror detailedError { get; set; }
}
```

If it's 200, the `response` object will be a `Routesummary`.

```
public class Routesummary
{
    public int lengthInMeters { get; set; }
    public int travelTimeInSeconds { get; set; }
    public int trafficDelayInSeconds { get; set; }
    public int trafficLengthInMeters { get; set; }
    public DateTime departureTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime arrivalTime { get; set; }
}
```

If it's 400, however, the `response` object will be an error message in the format of a string.

```
{
   "statusCode":400,
   "response":"Engine error while executing route request: MAP_MATCHING_FAILURE: Origin (0, 0)",
   "detailedError":{
      "message":"Engine error while executing route request: MAP_MATCHING_FAILURE: Origin (0, 0)",
      "code":"MAP_MATCHING_FAILURE"
   }
}
```

I'm using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rootobject>` but the issue I'm running into is, if I change the structure to hold a Routesummary, the deserialisation for a 400 response will fail - it will be a string.

I'm not sure how to check the response code based on the JSON and then tell the deserialiser to deserialise to a string/object based on the response.

I'm calling the Azure Maps API (Matrix routing).

Comment: If you want some help, you need to post all kind of json do you  neeed to deserialize, instead of this strange looking properties.

Comment: @Serge I have changed my question to give more information as to whats needed

Comment: Please [edit] and paste full JSON text

Comment: @ConorDrew Thanks, and could you pls post your json strings too in order  to test your code.

Comment: I have added the Json file that is returned with both 200 and 400 codes

Answer (score 2):

Use this version of the `Matrix` - the one with `response` set as a generic object - for deserialisation.

This will allow you to take a string in the case of 400 as well as a `Routesummary` object in the case of a 200, without any exceptions being thrown.

```
public class Matrix
{
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public object response { get; set; }
    public Detailederror detailedError { get; set; }
}
```

Once deserialised, do a simple check on the status code & depending on if it’s successful or not, cast appropriately.

```
if (matrix.statusCode is 200) {
    var routeSummary = (Routesummary)matrix.Response;
    ...
}
else {
    var errorMessage = (string)matrix.Response;
    var detailedError = matrix.detailedError;
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thank you, I think that makes sense, I have also just updated the post with a JSON example

Comment: @ConorDrew I've updated my answer based on the extra information you've provided - does this help?